# Render Text as Fixed Width and Height

Tags: wpf, richtextbox

I would like to somehow render a font as fixed width and fixed height even though it is not a monospace font. (I don't mind any distortions.)

I've looked in the documentation and a lot of SO questions, but cannot find what I am looking for.

Is there a built in feature for this, or would it be better to either override the rendering of the `RichTextBox` somehow or simply write my own renderer?

Comment: Talking about fixed height... you mean an `a` should have the same height as an `Ì` and a `.`?

Comment: Hi Have you tried FormattedText Class ?

Comment: @grek40 I would like the surrounding 'box' as it were to be the same height, that way when filled with a background color, all the characters line up.

Answer (score 1):

Use FormattedText Class [Formatted Text Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.formattedtext?view=netframework-4.7)

It is available in **System.Windows.Media**

```
Override OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
```

as given in link